# Difference between Vanguard sp500 UCITS and Vanguard sp500

Tags: united-states, stocks, eur-euro

I cannot understand the difference between these two:

- Ticker: VOO, name: [Vanguard 500 Index Fund ETF Class (USD)](http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0000P0N7)

and

- Ticker: VUSD, name: [Vanguard S&P 500 UCITS ETF (USD)](http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0000WA5P)

Buying them from Europe (Italy) are there any differences? (taxes, performance etc?

Comment: Request copies of the prospecti and compare them. You should be doing that any time you are evaluating one fund against another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that [VOO](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundIntExt=INT&FundId=0968#tab=0) trades on US stock exchanges while [VUSA/VUSD](https://www.vanguard.co.uk/uk/portal/detail/etf/overview?portId=9503&assetCode=EQUITY##overview) trade on the London Stock Exchange.  ([VUSA](https://www.google.com/finance?q=LON%3AVUSA) is listed in British pounds while [VUSD](https://www.google.com/finance?q=LON%3AVUSD) is listed in US dollars.)

They are essentially the same product, but the fees and legal hurdles for a European citizen to trade on the LSE may be quite different from those on US stock exchanges.